# Spring Security SAML ADFS Session Timeout Handelling

Tags: java, spring-security, session-timeout, adfs2.0, spring-saml

## Issue Due To Session-Time-Out

Hello,

We have two setups, one for dev other for production. Both are similar setups

SP side: Apache HTTPD Server + Tomcat Server
IDP side: ADFS 2.0

In Dev environment things are working fine. however in Production after some time interval of inactivity, I guess session time out happens when clicking on any hyperlink within application throws the following error:

`2014-09-12 10:37:32,759 [INFO] org.springframework.security.saml.log.SAMLDefaultLogger - AuthNResponse;FAILURE;192.168.21.11;qassocircle.someName.sim;http://idp.ssocircle.com;;;org.opensaml.common.SAMLException: Response has invalid status code urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Responder, status message is null
                at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.processAuthenticationResponse(WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.java:106)
                at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(SAMLAuthenticationProvider.java:81)
                at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:156)
                at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLProcessingFilter.attemptAuthentication(SAMLProcessingFilter.java:84)
                at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:195)
                at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
                at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
                at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:166)
                at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
                at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
                at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
                at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
                at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
                at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
                at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
                at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
                at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
                at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
                at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
                at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1008)
                at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)`

I have even tried to increase the maxAuthenticationAge for WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl to one day. However still even after inactivity of around 45 min, the user is getting the error.

Now since the issue is happening in Production and NOT in Dev. Debugging is becoming a challenge. If there are any pointer to be looked at, kindly do share.

Comment: What have you specified inside `session-timeout` in your web.xml?